# ISO 8601 Repeating Interval: every last day of month

Tags: time, mesos, iso, iso8601, mesos-chronos

Is it possible to define repeating interval for every last day of month in terms of ISO 8601?

I need this for several [Mesos/Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos) jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601:2004 does not specify.

ISO 8601-1:2019 and in particular ISO 8601-2:2019 (not freely available afaik) apparently clarifies in section 14 and Appendix D  that if an interval specifies a non-existing data then you back up to the last available day.  I take this to mean that R/2021-01-31P1M specifies the intervals 2021-01-31P1M, 2021-02-28P1M, 2021-03-31P1M etc.